# Allow small edit suggestions on beta sites

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

On Stack Overflow it makes perfect sense to reject tiny edits:

- there are several thousand questions per day
- there is a substantial number of users that have permission to edit questions
- users from the target group of SO are accustom to non wysiwyg editors

But on beta sites the situation is quite different:

- with about 5 to 10 questions per day, we want every single unclosed question to shine.
- there is only a very small number of uses which can directly edit questions. It is significant less work for them to accept/reject than to do the edit themselves. This is especially true for tedious formatting fixes
- it is a shame that interesting question look bad, just because the author is not used to markdown (e. g. has no empty line before a list)

**Fixing layout and spelling does make a lot of difference on the first impression of beta sites.**